# Android notifications customization

Tags: android, push-notification

Android notification shouldn't disappear after clicking the notification when tapped on it. Only after clicked on "clearall" then it should be cleared. How can I implement in Android?

Android notification shouldn't disappear after clicking the notification when tapped on it. Only after clicked on "clearall" then it should be cleared.
How can I implement in Android?

Comment: In NotificationBuilder don't add setContentIntent( )

Comment: Also, it will be better if you add your current NotificationService Class